# Read Data from different layout in android

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I have two classes and two layouts, I want to read the data of Edittext from layout A where I am writing the code in the class that has setcontentview of layout B.
 hope the above is clear.
Regards
Adam

Comment: Hm, no, at least for me it is not clear. What/how do you want to read?

Comment: I have added EditText to layout A, and i want to read the data of that EditText from a class that has ContentView of layout B.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the new Activity, you can send some args to it.

```
EditText mEditText = (EditText) findElementById(R.id.mEditText);
Intent mIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mString", mEditText.getText().toString());
startActivity(mIntent);
```

And to recover the data in the second Activity

```
String mString = getIntent().getStringExtra("mString");
```

Comment: Thank you,if I need to read More than two EditText, is it possible to create mEditText[], than  use mString[], please advise

Comment: Thank you Brayan, i found the solution:                        String[] mString=getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("mString");

Comment: You can send a lot of args with putExtra("name_of_arg", arg) and call back with getStringExtra("name_of_arg"), getIntExtra("name_of_arg") or other types, it depends what you send to intent.